# What happens in the following PHP script when several calls come in close together

Tags: php, mysql

This is properly going to be a daft question and i have googled this but struggled to find a clear answer.

I have a PHP script on a server, the actual script is insanely simple, it just sits on top of a MYSQL database.

It receives HTTP post messages containing a combination of strings and video files.

I'm obviously reading this data by $_POST['']

Now what I'm wondering is:
    If i make a call to the server the script is ran, this obviously takes a set amount of time.

What happens if another call to server is made before the previous set amount of time is completed?
My understanding is the script is loaded and i effectively have two running simultaneously. Is this correct? If so what happens in following example.

```
Message 1 comes in with data. PHP script starts running and reads two of the data 
bits in the message body.
Message 2 comes in and obviously a new PHP script is launched. 

    (So i have two scripts running, script 1 which is reading data from message 1, 
    and is half way though processing the data,   and script 2 just beginning).

What happens in the $_POST[''] in the first script? does it continue to read data from the message 1 or as message 2 has been received does it read data from that?
```

Although slightly different from above question it is kind of related.

I mentioned previously I'm interfacing to an SQL database, using the following

```
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

What happens if two scripts try and access same database/table at same time? Will MYSql be able to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: The better question is, what engine? InnoDB or MyISAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have two instances of the script running independently on the server, each with a separate PHP thread. The two are decoupled, so the second cannot read data from the request to the first, and vice versa. In answer to your second question, mysql will execute your SELECT queries simultaneously.

Comment: so please excuse my stupidity but if two calls came in, one has already connected to database, the other call will be able to also connect?

Comment: @DisplayName There is a set limit of the number of concurrent MySQL connections that your server can have, if that threshold if passed, you will receive [Too Many Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)

Comment: so if i put a check in on the connect, if that condition is present waits and tries to connect again that will be okay (in principle)

Comment: @DisplayName the limit of mysql connections is by default 151 in 5.6 and later: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/too-many-connections.html - you should be fine!

Comment: lol okay yeah i aint going to hit that. Thats great, thanks a lot